# Native iOS Facebook App shows empty canvas when called from FBLoginView

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

Environment:

- iOS 6.1.2
- Facebook SDK 3.2
- Facebook App Version 5.5 (current as of this post)
- OS level (native) Facebook connection **not configured**

Problem:

We are using FBLoginView to allow the user to connect with Facebook. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBLoginView/).

The expected flow is, that on pressing the FB Login button, iOS switches to the native Facebook App and asks the user for permission.

The switch works fine, the native Facebook App gets switched to foreground but all we see is the blue navigation bar with a Cancel button and a completely empty, white canvas.

If we drag the canvas, we do see the "Pull to refresh" animation, but no content whatsoever is displayed.

Is this currently broken? Do you see any of this or does it work for you?

We tripple-checked that the App ID and the configuration of the "conduit app on Facebook" has been set up correctly.

Comment: Have you found out what's wrong? I have the same issue

Comment: I also have the same issue